# How to fetch date, month and year from column with varchar data type?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having date column with varchar datatype. How to fetch day, month and year?

for example: "29/01/2015" is varchar type in SQL database.

Comment: Use SUBSTR to pick the different parts.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you have thus far to make the question more clear. This is extremely vague... I'm assuming you want to get the individual numbers and drop the '/' but that's not clear

Answer (score 1):

If your value is always in this format, just use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(col, '/', 1) as day,
       substring_index(substring_index(col, '/', 2), '/', -1) as month,
       substring_index(col, '/', -1) as year
```

However, you should store dates in the database using native date/time formats.  It makes operations on them much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(d,1,2) AS day, 
       SUBSTRING(d,4,2) AS month, 
       SUBSTRING(d,7,4) as year 
FROM t;
```

This query returns day, month and year as strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD') Day,
to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MM') MonthNum,
to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY') Year,
to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'MON') MonthChar,
to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'Dy') Weekday,
to_char(to_date('29/01/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DDD') JulianDay
from dual;
```